# Using tradingview pine script to make strategy for backtesting

Tags: python, pine-script, back-testing

I am currently trying to make a strategy for backtesting. I want to know the code for closing the position. when the candle is closed. it is buying in open and selling in close in 4h chart. please giving me advice :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your strategy on pine script code, make sure to state True to process_orders_on_close.

```
strategy("your_strategy",process_orders_on_close = true)
```

Pine Script default is to execute an order on the next candle once the trigger is active.